# How to implement Android Snack bar or WhatsApp notification feature in ios that supports all iOS devices

Tags: ios, android-snackbar

I am new to iOS development.I want to notify user when some action is done. In Android they are providing snack bar to achieve this.I saw lot of libraries.I am not sure which is standard library support for all iOS devices.

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=notification

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can create an extension of **UIViewController**  and show a label on it depending on position.

```
enum ToastPosition {
case top
case down
}

extension UIViewController {


func show(toastWith message : String, font: UIFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12) ,toastPosition: ToastPosition,backgroundColor: UIColor = .black,textColor: UIColor = .white, duration: TimeInterval = 3.0) {

    let yPostition = toastPosition == .top ? 24 : self.view.frame.size.height - 44 - 16//margin

    let frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width/2 - 64, y: yPostition, width: 150, height: 44)

    let toast = UILabel(frame: frame)
    toast.backgroundColor = backgroundColor.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
    toast.textColor = textColor
    toast.textAlignment = .center;
    toast.font = font
    toast.text = message
    toast.alpha = 1.0
    toast.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    toast.clipsToBounds  =  true
    self.view.addSubview(toast)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.1, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        toast.alpha = 0.0
    }, completion: {(isCompleted) in
        toast.removeFromSuperview()
    })
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is one that is standard but I'm using https://github.com/Daltron/NotificationBanner which works pretty well and is still maintained.

Comment: It also has a bottom notification bar which is really close to the snackbar

Comment: Thank you Xavier.Looking for more suggestions